# Admin sometimes redirects to HTTPS

Tags: wp-admin, redirect, debug, https

I have multiple Wordpress installations hosted at Hostinger.

Sometimes, when I save a post or, as happened right now, just tried to access wp-admin, it redirects me to HTTPS version of the website.

It happens randomly with all my websites, I just type in the address again and it works normally.

It's a strange bug, my settings are set to HTTP, I don't know much else to say. Anyone got any ideas to debug this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you have "HTTPS Everywhere" or similar in your browser?

Comment: No, I tried it on my phone (3G), my sister's computer, my laptop and my PC - all gave the same error, even in fresh websites I tested in Hostinger - it's server side

Comment: Yes it does seem like a server-side error.

Comment: I’m just going to say it: “Add https to your site!!! It’s easy. Visit https://letsencrypt.org/.” If your host doesn’t offer https for free, do it yourself!

Answer (score 1):

Finally, after MONTHS I was able to solve it.

Just add

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME'] = 'http';
$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] = 80;
```

To wp-config.php, preferably before calling wp-settings.php

Thanks to Daan Meijer for this.

PS: It was a server-side error, probably something to do with PHP process manager such as php-fpm or mod_php. The hosting company solved it without the need for the hack above.